# Carregando um relatorio em Web Forms

Tags: c#, webforms, relatório, crystal-reports

Pretendo gerar alguns relatórios em minha aplicação e estou usando Crystal Reports.
O Relatório em si está correto porém eu não consigo carrega-lo em minha pagina (.aspx).

Segue o código do evento Load de minha aplicação:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = new ReportDocument();

    doc.Load(MapPath("~/Relatorios/MeuRelatorio.rpt"));
    doc.SetDatabaseLogon("my_user","senha123");

    this.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
    this.CrystalReportViewer1.PrintMode = PrintMode.Pdf;
    this.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

O código não exibe nada na página, mas debugando eu consegui ver todos os resultados inseridos na variavel **doc**. Consegui ver suas linhas, resultado de sucesso de login e etc.

Eu sei que em MVC eu consigo dar um **return** na **Action** com o tipo **File**, e no **File** eu exporto o resultado do relatório, exemplo:

```
public ActionResult Relatorio()
{
    //Restante do código

    //Exporta em pdf à variável "stream"
    Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    rptH.Refresh();
    //Retorna o tipo File
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

Porém em Web Forms eu não tenho a mínima idéia de como extraio essas informações na tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o que faltava em meu código. É necessário utilizar o método **ExportToHttpResponse()** da classe **ReportDocument()** no qual pede alguns parâmetros como:

- O tipo de exportação (pdf, xls, txt..)
- O Response
- Um booleano que indica se será exportado em download ou não
- O nome do relatório

Exemplo:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = new ReportDocument();

    doc.Load(MapPath("~/Relatorios/MeuRelatorio.rpt"));
    doc.SetDatabaseLogon("my_user","senha123");

    doc.Refresh();
    doc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, MapPath("~/Relatorios/MeuRelatorio.rpt"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;.filename=SeuReport.pdf");
// Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", coloque aqui o tamanho do arquivo em bytes);
Response.ContentType = "Application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
rptH.Refresh();
Response.End();
```

Não testei esse código, mas acredito que com algumas modificações você consiga chegar no resultado esperado.

Comment: Obrigado @Cigano! Não solucionou, mas deu uma luz. A solução está publicada.